# Why is "DMV" different from a language point of view in Linguistics?

Tags: meaning, terminology, linguistics

What is the speaker referring to when, talking about two phrasal verbs, they say

> They may be equivalent as far as **the DMV is concerned**, but they're not equivalent from the point of view of language.

I looked up DMV and I *think* it is an initialisation of the Dependency Model with Valence, I found a reference and an explanation (of sorts) in a book titled *[Grammatical Inference for Computational Linguistics](https://books.google.it/books?id=LrnSCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=DMV%20linguistics&source=bl&ots=hcAxKDhWjN&sig=9OCPeOXVcvR2pnSoM8Ok9QrYE24&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK-OCGvt3YAhVIkRQKHX3WDkcQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=DMV%20linguistics&f=false)* but despite reading its description, I still cannot get to grips with it, i.e. I don't understand.

> **DMV.** The Dependency Model with Valence (DMV) is an unsupervised dependency parser. Instead of a one-to-many mapping between non-terminals (on the left-hand side) and terminals or non-terminals (on the right-hand-side) in, for instance, context-free grammar, dependency models are a one-to-one mapping. Essentially, dependencies describe head-dependent relationships between the words in a sentence. This results in directed acyclic graphs; for instance, like the one depicted in Figure 4.6.

Unfortunately, Figure 4.6 is missing from my preview.

Could someone please explain, in layman's terms, what DMV is and provide examples where a verb with two different prepositions can have very similar meanings, which can be equivalent to DMV,  but not equivalent from a language point of view.

For example, would ***go round*** and ***go around*** OR ***look through*** and ***look over*** be equivalent to DMV but not from a language point of view? Why?

Comment: Lucky that we have people like this, to explain English to us!

Comment: Wouldn't this be better asked on https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user159691 fair point but this site is also for "linguists" and "etymologists" I don't want to join SE Linguistics  for one question, there are a number of linguists on EL&U who might be able to explain  DMV, in simple terms, to a numbskull like myself.

Comment: I see, actually there is n Etymology site on SE, unlike Linguistics.

Comment: @user159691 I know but the description on the tour page hasn't changed, it still says that EL&U is a site for linguists etc. etc.

Comment: DMV can refer to Delaware-Maryland-Virginia (or DC-Maryland-Virginia) which I mention only because the Smith and Tangier Island dialect is in the Chesapeake Bay in the middle of this geography. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2501/has-the-tangier-island-accent-truly-remained-unchanged-since-the-elizabethan-per

Comment: Could you include the context where you first came across this? What are the phrasal verbs in question, and how are they being discussed? The quote would make some sense if we take _DMV_ to refer to the Dependency Model with Valence. This is a computational linguistics parser, i.e., a model/pattern that computers can use to parse their way through language samples and markup words/constituents in relation to one another. Two phrasal verbs may end up being parsed identically in the DMV even though they’re semantically or grammatically very different in actual language. That would be my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way of thinking about a DMV is as a kind of tree-like representation of a parsed phrase.  Here is an example taken from [the Wikipedia page for "Dependency Grammar."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar)

[image]

This is an "unordered tree" of the sentence:

> That thing I will never forget.

However, you would get the same tree if you were parsing the sentence:

> I will never forget that thing.

So comparing those two sentences, one might say:

> They may be equivalent **as far as the DMV is concerned,** but they're not equivalent from the point of view of language.

I'm not sure whether or not this example will help you understand the comment addressed to you without knowing more detail.

Comment: Thanks for making it simpler for me to get to grips with. You did a good job.

Comment: The two sentences in your answer, their meanings are the same, aren't they? If I said *"We went round the block"* vs *"We went around the block"* would they be equivalent as far as... blah, blah, blah ? Or, for example, "*Please look through your form*" vs "*Please look over your form*" if I were to say they mean the same, i.e there is no difference in meaning,  would the speaker's response make sense?

Comment: @Mari-LouA to me, if the preposition is changed, then the speaker's response is less clear.  Perhaps they mean that the *structure* (or "shape") of the DMV would look the same, if not the actual words.  Perhaps their point was "This has subtle differences in meaning even though its structure is the same," or something along those lines